# jQuery error function inside of a for loop that loads an image array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, image

I created several arrays like this:

```
var project1 = new Array();
var project2 = new Array();
var project3 = new Array();
```

i wrote a function with a for loop inside to load images to those arrays like so:

```
function loadProject(whichCount, whichProject, whichImages){
    for(let i = 1; i <= whichCount; i++){
        whichProject[i] = new Image();
        whichProject[i].src = whichImages + i + '.jpg';
    };
};

loadProject(max1, project1, 'content/images/archive/archive');
loadProject(max2, project2, 'content/images/celine/celine');
loadProject(max3, project3, 'content/images/chair/chair');
```

like this, this code works fine. Now I want to be flexible to use either jpgs and pngs.
Unfortunately the way I tried to approach wouldn't work out. Maybe because that's not how I call the object?

```
function loadProject(whichCount, whichProject, whichImages){
    for(let i = 1; i <= whichCount; i++){
        whichProject[i] = new Image();
        whichProject[i].src = whichImages + i + '.jpg';
        whichProject[i].on('error', function() {
            whichProject[i].src = whichImages + i + '.png';
        });
    };
};
```

**EDIT:** I added `let` to `i = 1`

Comment: You're not really using any jQuery anywhere, until you try to assign the error event handler. You need `$(whichProject[i]).on(...)` instead.

Comment: Use `for(let i = 1` and you should be good.